# How to put the date into firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have configured the firebase requirement.

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Inside the html code i create an input. Input type is date then it will pop out a datepicker. But inside the javascript, i dont know how to convert the date into a value therefore it able store in firebase database.

```js
var d = document.getElementById("datepicker");

function submit(){

var entereddate= d.toString();


firebaseRef.push().set(entereddate);


}
```

```html
 <input type="date" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
 <button onclick="submit()" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that may be preventing this from working. 
You first have to add the configuration that Firebase requires:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

After you initialize whats required, you then get an instance of the database:

```
// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();
```

And then finally push it to the database:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
});
```

Comment: I have confirgured the firebase requirement. I just cannot push the date into the database.

Comment: Are you sure that when you push to the database, it is actually being called? log the console before and after you push to the database, to see where it is not working.

Comment: ya , i cant get the datepicker value in js.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push data with push key:

```
firebase.database().ref('yourDataIndex/').push({
datetime: new Date() //or your picker date
});
```

If you want to set only one data without push key:

```
firebase.database().ref('yourDataIndex/').set({
datetime: new Date() //or your picker date
});
```

And if you want to update your existing data (it is like set data you can set data this too)

```
firebase.database().ref('yourDataIndex/' + your push key here).update({
datetime: new Date() //or your picker date
});
```

Comment: i dont know how to parse the date in js. I cant  get the value of the datepicker in the js.

Comment: You can find it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript